# How to create a reusable function in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm a quite new to React so sorry if this is a simple question. I have a bunch of components, and for each component I would like to specify an initial state for each of {b: this.constructor.displayName} ("b" is to be used when building classNames). Rather than define b in "getInitialState" initial state in every component, I would like to define some reusable function to set b everywhere.

From my early research it seems like mixins might be promising. However, I've also read that mixins are on their way out. What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to look into using a library like `redux`, this would allow you to have a global state that all components can access (if requested). http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html - At first it may seem hard to get your head around but eventually you'll understand it :)

Comment: mixins are already out, especially if you want to use ES6 classes (which makes how they worked is literally impossible). One thing I can recommend is first run through the React tutorials on the facebook github page for React. They're quite good, and combined with an understanding of regular JS lets you figure out how to do a lot of things. React is not magic: it's just more javascript, so the same JS rules apply: you can import any regular JS function and run it on top of whatever to put into React.createClass first, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current way to do this in React is to use composition rather than mixins.  Composition is also known as "higher-order components" and looks a bit like this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{ this.props.b }</div>;
    }
}

const EmbedClassName = function(Child) {
    var b = Child.constructor.displayName;
    return (props) => <Child {...props} b={b} />;
};

var ComposedFoo = EmbedClassName(Foo);
```